# How to integrate hubspot chat on electron app

Tags: electron, hubspot

I'm trying to integrate hubspot chat on an electron app.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://js.hs-scripts.com/xxxxxx.js" defer async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As the app is not served via a classic http server so the bubble doesn't show up.

If you open this html file directly in your browser like this :

> file:///C:/Users/Foo/Desktop/index.html

The chatbox won't show. But the js file is well fetched.

I've tried :

1. //js.hs-scripts.com/xxx.js
2. http://js.hs-scripts.com/xxx.js
3. https://js.hs-scripts.com/xxx.js

What can I do to use the chat in my Electron app ?

Comment: It might be because it's not served from a domain it doesn't recognize? Do you provide your api keys to authenticate your chat?